# Sharepoint Online remote event receiver without App/Add-in

Tags: event-handling, sharepoint-online

The company I work for uses SharePoint Online. We have a requirement that on most site collections, whenever a user creates a new document library that the document library is configured with the "document" content type being removed, and replaced with some of our own corporate content types.
Previously I've managed this by using a coded sandbox solution installed on relevant site collections which had an event handler that fired on "list added". It's obviously now time to move away from that solution.

I'm really struggling to get to grips with the alternative, conceptually. I'm aiming to replace the old solution with a Remote Event Receiver solution.

The way I think I'd like to achieve this:
1) Create a single remote event receiver hosted in Azure which receives details of a new list being added in a site which it then configures appropriately.
2) Use CSOM to provision the site and as part of that provisioning, hook up the event receiver.

I've spent a lot of time on this, getting nowhere. I initially thought the answer lied in using an App which I could install in the App Catalog and then push out to particular site collections but that doesn't seem to be right.

Is the solution above possible? All examples on the web I've come across of setting up remote event receivers seem to use a SharePoint app which I don't really want to do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For info I found the answer. You can indeed create a remote event receiver without a SharePoint app/add-in.
The answer was written up here
[I thought I needed a SharePoint Provider Hosted App for that part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/boodablog/2015/01/12/i-thought-i-needed-a-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-for-that-part-1/)

But you should bear in mind that as per [Remove event receivers on host web clientContext](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/07/remote-event-receivers-on-host-web-ClientContext.html) you will not have the client Context passed through, so

```
TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties)
```

...will come through as empty. If you want to interact with SharePoint then you'll need to find another way than this approach, or use a different set of credentials.